# NODE - wait until one api call has completed before triggering the next api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am making a POST request in one of my routes add-users. I have created an array called success. Once the request has returned the response I want to trigger the next API call.

It is not working at the moment as I think I am sending too may API requests at once. I think the solution is that I wait until the first response has returned a response and finished, and then trigger the next API call.

Is this assumption correct? If so, can anyone advise how to implement this? I have tried to use `.on('end'....`

Please see my code below.

```
app.get('/add-users', function (req, res) {

    var success = [];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var name = users[i].userId;
        request({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + users[i].accessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'PUT',
            json: true
        }, function(err, resp, body){
            if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
                success.push(name);
            }
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            console.log('this is the end');
            count++;
            if(count === users.length) {
                res.json(success);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic! I've had this issue as well when I was first dealing with node.

Lemme explain by first copying some parts of your code:

```
app.get('/add-users', function (req, res) {
    // [...]
    for(/* user in users */) {
        request(/* [...] */)
        .on('end', function(){
            console.log('this is the end');
            count++;
            if(count === users.length) {
                res.json(success);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Node, in contrast to other languages (e.g. Ruby) does non-blocking I/O. This means that it performs almost all I/O operations (like making an HTTP request) asynchronously. Essentially, when you initiate a request, it will not wait for the response.

In your loop this means that it will fire all requests one after the other without waiting for their responses:

```
start loop
  make request
  make request
  make request
end of loop

... a little later
handle response
handle response
handle response
```

I assume that what you want looks like this:

```
start loop
  make request
  handle response
  make request
  handle response
  make request
  handle response
end of loop
```

One trick I found to get around node's non-blocking nature and do sequential requests is to write a recursive function like this:

```
function getAllUsers(users) {
    function getOneUser(users) {
        let user = users.pop();
        request(/* [...] */)
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log("done with ONE user");
                if(users.length) { // do we still have users to make requests?
                    getOneUser(users); // recursion
                } else {
                    console.log("done with ALL users");
                    res.json(success);
                }
            });
    }

    // make a copy of the original users Array because we're going to mutate it
    getOneUser(Array.from(users)); 
}
```

What the above will do is make one request for one user, then when the response arrives fire another request.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @phantom does it throw any exception? (sorry I accidentally deleted your comment)

Comment: i have changed the code to use sessions. The array is now `req.session.users`. This means the code at the end looks like `getOneUser(Array.from(req.session.users));` Does the code in the recursive function remain called `users` as this is the argument passed in or do I need to change it to `req.session.users` . i.e. should it be `if(users.length) ...` or `if(req.session.users.length) ...`

Comment: In my code the recursive function's `users` argument was shadowing the external one (I should have renamed it). You can keep it named `users`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually chain multiple requests together.  Attempting to call an async function within a loop will not work the way you have written your code.  Instead I would recommend calling the next request in the callback of your initial request.

```
//set index
var index = 0;
function callAPI(user) {
    //increment index
    index++
    request({request:object},function(err, res){
      if (index <= users.length) {
        callAPI(users[index])
      }
    });
}
//call function with 0 index
callApi(users[0])
```

Also, if you console.log(name) in your code above you will see the issue for yourself.